# Oracle SQL count of date columns

Tags: oracle, select

I just want to count duplicated dae columnds in my table. My tables are like that:

**VISIT**:

```
ID_VISIT FK_PATIENT DATEA
0        1          20160425
1        2          20160425
2        3          20160426
```

I tried these :

```
SELECT VISIT.DATEA, COUNT(VISIT.DATEA) as numberOfDate FROM VISIT
SELECT VISIT.DATEA, COUNT(VISIT.DATEA) as numberOfDate FROM VISIT GROUP BY numberOfDate
```

but I got only like this :

```
DATEA    NUMBEROFDATE
20160502 1
20160430 1
20160503 1
20160501 1
20160429 1
20160425 1
20160425 1
20160425 1
20160428 1
20160504 1
```

but I want to get like this

```
DATEA    NUMBEROFDATE
20160502 1
20160430 1
20160503 1
20160501 1
20160429 1
20160425 3
20160428 1
20160504 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the column you want to be unique. Then aggregate functions like `count()` apply to each group

```
SELECT DATEA, COUNT(DATEA) as numberOfDate 
FROM VISIT 
GROUP BY DATEA
```